# jQuery-UI datepicker: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'zIndex'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to use the jQuery datepicker plugin but I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'zIndex'
```

I'm using jQuery v1.10.2 and jQuery UI Datepicker v1.10.3. This is how I try to call the datepicker method

```
<input type="text" id="foo" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/my/path/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/my/path/js/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#foo").datepicker();
</script><script type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem like you're missing core `jQueryUI` file, try to add it to your page and it should be fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/my/path/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/my/path/js/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have you jquery file as there are stored on the server

use the following link as they worked for tried & tested on my system

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

to have css of jquery datepicker use the following file

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

Must be certain problem with your js files

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that the DOM isn't completely loaded. The initialization of the datepicker should be done in the "document ready" function like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#foo").datepicker();
});
```